# HTML email signature file black borders in reply

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I have an HTML file that I use as an email signature footer at work (we use IBM Notes).

When I create an email, it looks great. The logo is in place, the text is bold where I want to it to be, to logo is to the left of the address.

However, when someone replies to my emails the footer looks messy. All the borders of the cells are black lines.

I don't want the ugly black lines.

When I reply to emails I often get a dialogue box appear saying "Multilingual MIME Warning - You are sending or saving a document which requires more than one character set when it is converted to MIME (Internet mail) format. Which character set should be used for the document?
  (*) Unicode (the UTF8 multilingual character set)
  ( ) Best native character set (best matching native character set for text in document).
The most representable character set is ISO-8859-1

I don't know if this dialogue is related to the black lines.

This is the HTML, thanks in adance.

﻿

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1 {color:red;}
p {color:black;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table border=0><font face="Arial">
<tr>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan=3 align="center">
    <font face="Arial" size="3">
      <strong>
        Comet Bill
      </strong>
    </font><br />
    <strong>
    <font face="Arial" size="3">
        Bit herder
    </font></strong>
  </td>
  <td align="center">
    <img src='XYZourstrapline.png' align="center">
  </td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr>
  <td align="right" width="10%"><img src='XYZ Corp logo.png'>
  </td>
  <td colspan=3>
    <font face="arial" size="3">
      XYZ Corporation Ltd.
    </font><br />
    <font face="Arial" size="2">Hard Way, Impossible Road,
    <br />GitVille, XY3 1XY</font>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
<table border=0>
<tr>
  <td colspan=1 align="right">
    <font face="Arial" size="1">Switchboard:</font>
  </td>
  <td colspan=3>
    <font face="Arial" size="2">+44 (0)1234 567890</font>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan=1 align="right">
    <font face="Arial" size="1">Direct:</font>
  </td>
  <td colspan=3>
    <font face="Arial" size="2">+44 (0)1234 987654</font>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan=1 align="right">
    <font face="Arial" size="1">Email:
    </font>
  </td>
  <td colspan=3>
    <font face="Arial" size="2">comet.bill@myemailaddress.com</font>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can't put a font tag after the opening table tag - it's invalid.  Also the font tag was deprecated in html4 and obsolete in html5 so I'm not sure it will be useful in an email template

Comment: Thanks @Pete, so what should I use instead to control the font size?

Comment: use inline styles - `<strong style="font-family: arial; font-size="14pt">Comet Bill</strong>'  may not solve the border problem, but as email browsers can't handle html very well, it will be one less thing that can go wrong.  Also remove your row with empty `th` tags, your empty `tr` tag

Comment: Also make sure the number of columns in each row match - in your first table, you have 4, 5 and then 4 again, in your second table, there is no need for any colspans.  Sorry my comment for font size above was wrong - should be `font-size:14pt;`

Comment: Cheers @Pete. I will continue to have a tinker tomorrow when I'm back in work. I used the colspans to get the text to look 'right' so that the address spreads out underneath the name 'box' and the big logo 'box'.

Comment: How's this work: http://jsfiddle.net/nqe4n27t/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your style tag in your head:

```
tr,td,table,th{border:none;}
```

Comment: That makes it worse. That gives a thick black border around everything when I create a new email.

Comment: This is what I ended up with :-
<head>
<style>
h1 {color:red;}
p {color:black;}
tr, td, table, th {border:none;}
</style>
</head>

Comment: You should put the code in the style tag which is inside the head. Sorry about that... edited.

Also, the comment from @Pete about inline styles may yield better results.